# Entering while loop repeatedly before stopping at getchar()

Tags: c

I'm writing a simple C program in which I want to validate my user's input for integers from 1-9.

The logic for my code seems fine but for some reason if I type "lll" for my input (or any other random input not between 1-9), it will show the error message inside the while loop a couple of times before actually stopping at the getchar() once again.

```
 /**
 * Validate user input and reprompt if invalid
 * @return input -  Users valid input
 */
int validateUserInput() {
    int firstInput = getchar() - 48;
    int secondInput = getchar();

        while(secondInput != 10 || firstInput >= 10 || firstInput <= 0 ){
            printf("Invalid Input. Please try again. \nEnter a number between (1-9): ");

            firstInput = getchar() - 48;
            secondInput = getchar();
        }

    return firstInput;
}
```

The logic is that:

- Invalid Input - If the second input != 10 which means that the second char is something other than the enter key.
- Invalid Input - If the first char subtracted 48 is higher than 9 or less than 1 then it's too high.

The logic seems fine to me but here's some output when I enter random characters:

```
Enter a number between 1-9: lllll
Invalid Input. Please try again.
Enter a number between 1-9: Invalid Input. Please try again.
Enter a number between 1-9: Invalid Input. Please try again.
Enter a number between 1-9: Invalid Input. Please try again.
Enter a number between 1-9: Invalid Input. Please try again.
Enter a number between 1-9: Invalid Input. Please try again.
Enter a number between 1-9:
```

Why does it repeat that message so many times before actually letting me enter input again? This is all that's wrong with my program.

Comment: All those "ells" are sitting there in the input buffer. They don't go away until you read them.

Comment: Avoid using "magic numbers" like 48 and 10.  Instead maybe do something like this: `#define ENTER_KEY 10`.

Comment: @iRove thank you for your suggestion. I have done this for all of my magic numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is fine. But the invalid characters you input still remain in the input buffer. So, the subsequent calls to `getchar()` read them.

Whenever you hit an invalid input, you want to ignore them all. You can read them out using a loop like this:

```
  while(secondInput != 10 || firstInput >= 10 || firstInput <= 0 ){
     printf("Invalid Input. Please try again. \nEnter a number between (1-9): ");
     int i;
     while((i=getchar()) != '\n' && i != EOF);
     ...
```

Having said that it's generally hard to use `getchar()` and `scanf()` family functions to correctly read interactive input and do error checking. A better way would be to read *lines* (such as `fgets()`) and parse/error check them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm sorry I understand what you mean but not 100% your solution. I added `int i;
            while((i=getchar() != EOF) && i != '\n');` where you suggested and left the rest and it works great on the first run but it gets stuck on the loop on every run after. Thank you

Comment: @Walker I modified that loop slightly. See the update. And also note the warnings about `getchar()`, `scanf()` etc :)

Comment: This does not work. Did you try it? You have brackets in the wrong place - precedence.

Comment: @usr thank you so much man. This works great. The greatest challenge of this assignment was to not be able to use higher level constructs. But thank you so much for your suggestion. I will definitely look into it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Indeed. Fixed the brackets. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you entered 5 chars. 5x L. You are checking only one char, but by what did you wrote I guess you want to check whole input charr array. So then you cant use getChar().